# How to build network-manager-openvpn and network-manager-openvpn-gnome

Tags: gnome, network-manager, compiling, openvpn

Long story short, I want to build `network-manager-openvpn` and/or `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` from source, to fix an oooold bug in this tool (ask by many persons for more than 10 years...) and add the up/down script capacity.
Before applying this fix, I just want to succeed a simple build from sources... But no success. I think (I'm sure) I'm missing something, but I don't know why...

**Who am I:** And devop that try to improve his desktop environment

**My environment:** Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop (bionic)

**What I tried:**

```bsh
git clone https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn
cd network-manager-openvpn
./configure
make
sudo make install
# result successful
```

**What I expected:**
Same things as if I had installed `network-manager-openvpn` (that comes with `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`) from APT
[image: Network Manager GUI with OpenVPN option]
[image: Network Manager GUI with OpenVPN edition]

**What I have after `sudo make install` of these sources:**
No OpenVPN option, cannot open a .ovpn file, and an error if I want to edit a previous .ovpn imported configuration...
[image: Network Manager GUI without OpenVPN option]
[image: Network Manager GUI without OpenVPN edition]

I appeal to your profesionnal knowledge to help me in this war against the machines...

Thanks !

Comment: Try to build the package using the package source and rebuild the package applying needed fixes. For example in this way: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/ Of course, you are able to find other tutorials on google.

Comment: The problem is you used `./configure` without arguments. Primarily, the build was done using the default prefix of `/usr/local/` which is where it installed to, while network-manager is in `/usr/` so it's likely not finding the add-ons. There are probably other options you need too. As above, it's best to build the debian package (run `debuild` in the tree), and then install the resulting debs.

Comment: `sudo apt-get source network-manager-openvpn` return `E: Impossible de trouver une source de paquet pour network-manager-openvpn` ; `debuild` ask for a tar.gz...